# How to view data form two table join data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have to table 
This is classroom table
[image]

And this is joinclass table
[image]

Now i want to view classroom data which class_code match form joinclass table.
Here is my classroom model

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class classroom extends Model
{


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

And this is my join class model

```
 <?php

namespace App\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class joinclass extends Model
{
    public $timestamps= true;
    protected $table='joinclass';
    protected $guarded=['id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

So now what should to write in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following simple join query first, and then integrate it with your tables

```
  $arr_tags = DB::table('tags')
                        ->join('users','users.id','=','tags.user_id')
                        ->select('tags.id','tags.status','tags.tag_name','users.first_name','users.last_name','tags.created_at','tags.updated_at')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: I am trying this procese but can't do. Can you give me full model and controller code? please.